# how do I display the elements in the slice all on one line separated by a single space and sorted in highest to lowest order

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am supposed to define a function called process and within this function 
it needs to display the elements in the slice all on one line separated by a single space and sorted in highest to lowest order.And I need to use a for loop in process function.

---

```
def main():
    import random

    nums=[]

    for i in range(7):
        nums.append (random.randrange(20,80))
        result=nums

    while 20 <= result <=80:
        pass
    print result
    print ("The highest number is"),max(result)
    print ("The lowest number is"), min(result)

    #result.sort()
    print ("The middle 5 sorted high to low:")
    print (process (result))

def process(total):
    for num in total:
        result.sort()
        #print ("The middle 5 sorted high to low:")
    return result


main()
```

---

The output should look like this

```
[67, 73, 24, 33, 70, 33, 47]
The highest number is 73
The lowest number is 24
The middle 5 sorted high to low:
[24, 33, 33, 47, 67]
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a for loop in the process function?

Comment: Your example with "The middle 5 sorted high to low" doesn't make sense

Comment: @user38034 so the  elements cannot be displayed inside [ ] separated by commas

Comment: The `while ...: pass` loop does nothing. You show no slices `[x:y]`; if you sort `result` then `result[0]` contains the min and `result[-1]` contains the max and `result[1:-1]` contains a list of the middle.

Comment: You wrote: "The output should look like this" and then provided a weird output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following. Doesn't use a loop, just sorting and slicing.

```
def process(total):
    total.sort()
    return total[1:-1] #take all numbers except the first and the last
```

Comment: Thank you,that solution works.But, my other concern is the for loop that he wants me to implement within the process function.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work.

Some of the things I noticed in your code is that the process function calls result, which is NOT defined inside the function (you may want to read about Python variable scopes). Also, the while loop is completely useless.

```
import random

def main():

    nums=[]

    for i in range(7):
        nums.append( random.randrange(20,80) )

    print nums
    print ("The highest number is"), max(nums)
    print ("The lowest number is"), min(nums)

    print ("The middle 5 sorted from high to low:")
    print ( sorted(nums)[1:-1] )

main()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You need to swap the order of the sorting and slicing operations.

Comment: @TechSpy, my teacher told me to use only the while loop to display the seven integers.

Comment: @user38034 Right, I overlooked that minor detail. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like what you're trying to accomplish:

```
def main():
    import random

    nums=[]

    for i in range(7):
        nums.append (random.randrange(20,80))
        result=nums

    print (result)
    print ("The highest number is " ,max(result))
    print ("The lowest number is " , min(result))

    #result.sort()
    print ("The middle 5 sorted high to low:")
    process (result)

def process(total):
    dist_from_ends = (len(total) - 5) // 2
    slice_ = total[dist_from_ends:-dist_from_ends]

    for number in sorted(slice_):
        print(number, end=" ")
        # this only works in Python3
```

This results in output of:

```
[69, 57, 31, 60, 64, 64, 36]
The highest number is  69
The lowest number is  31
The middle 5 sorted high to low:
31 57 60 64 64
```